# Resigning IPA (with push notifications) for Enterprise

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

We have an ios app, set up with push notifications, all signed and available via the app store.

The client wants to sign this with their enterprise account and distribute internally.

As the ios dev accounts are different, I assume the App ID will need to change?
And if the app ID changes, they will need to re configure the push notifications?

Comment: yes check in your Push Notifications  in your developer account -> Identifiers - > Select your app id and edit and enable Push notification.

Comment: Matt, Just want to know if you want to keep the App on App Store as well and Distribute internally?

Comment: No, it will be enterprise only.  If we transferred the app from our account to theirs, would that solve the issue, as the bundle ID would remain the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES, You need to crate all the procedure again